# 404 not found when storing data laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

when i click on the submit button it returns the route with 404 page

this is the blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('comment.store') }}" >
      @csrf
     <input type="text">
     <button type="submit">Add comment</button>
</form>
```

the comment controller:

```
    class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $film = Film::findOrFail($request->film_id);

        Comment::create([
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'post_id' => $film->id
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('showFilm', $film->id);
    }
}
```

and this is my web.php:

```
Route::post('comment/store', [CommentController::class, 'store'])->name('comment.store');
```

Comment: you're redirecting to the route named ``showFilm`` after saving the data. Does the ``showFilm`` route exist?

Comment: Looks like you have not any route named ``showFilm``

Comment: i do have showFilm, the comment form is in showFilm blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using `findOrFail()` method, which, as it's name implies, will return your model if it's found, otherwise, will you show you a 404 page. You should validate film_id in the store method

Edit: Add a hidden input with your film_id in your view

```
           <form method="POST" action="{{ route('comment.store') }}" >
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="film_id" value="{{ $film->id }}">
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add comment..">
                <button type="submit" class="submit">Add comment</button>
               </div>
           </form>
```

that way, film_id will be sent to your controller

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: in your view, do you have a <input type="hidden" name="film_id" value={{ $film->id }}>?

Comment: when i do dd($film) it returns null

Comment: and no i don't have that in my view

Comment: Check out my edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your `findOrFail()` method return this **404** error, cause `$request->film_id` is null

Comment: how to fix that?